# Weighted Resistor DAC Equation

Tags: digital-logic, analog, logic-gates, conversion

I'm trying to study DAC .. In my reference text book the equation is given as follows 
[image]

[image]

On some online sources 2 is given as the subscript.Please see

https://www.allsyllabus.com/aj/note/ECE/LINEAR_ICs_and_APPLICATIONS/unit4/BINARY-WEIGHTED%20RESISTOR%20DAC.php#.WnQT2DNX7qA

I was wondering if my text book is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have posted pictures of a DAC, and a link to one. They have identical function.

The line of resistors has a factor of 2 between them, they are binary weighted.

The resistors are switched either between 2 voltages (your picture) or between connected and unconnected (your link). In both this changes a current through them. As the resistors are scaled in binary, the currents are scaled in binary.

The currents are summed at a summing amplifier. The output voltage is proportional to the sum of resistor currents.

There are notation differences between the two, they are unimportant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... To be clear I'm referring to the 2^0A3 etc... In my text the 2 is at the top,while on the  online source 2 is a sub script.

Comment: I see all the coefficients, the As whether upper or lower case,  using subscripts to identify them, though one lot are numbered 0-3, and the others 1-4. All the 2s use superscripts, to show the power they're raised to, again 0-3 in one reference and 1-4 in the other. These are not significant differences. If I'm still missing something, you'll need to edit your question and point at the specific equations you take issue with.